# using CSS to 'pop-out' a div in a list of divs

Tags: html, css

I'm looking for a pure CSS solution to do the following: Given some HTML structure

```
<div>
    <div>[content 1]</div>
    <div class="expanded">[some bigger content 2]</div>
    <div>[content 3]</div>
    <div>[content 4]</div>
</div>
```

have it display like:

> [content 1] [content 3] [content 4]
>
> [ s o m e   b i g g e r   c o n t e n t   2 ]

(edit: I've uploaded a screenshot of the solution of Illimar Pihlamäe, this is about what I want)
[image: example]
I need the css to make the `expanded` content *pop-out*. How do I do this, and is there a name for this technique?

I'd prefer a non-javascript solution.

Comment: From your display description, I wouldn't call it pop-out. Do you have an image of what you are trying to achieve. Try uploading it to an image sharing site like imgur and post a link here.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm understanding. You've already targeted it with a class, so why can't you just set the CSS directly?

Comment: Is this on `:hover` or just on a div that has this class? An image, like Chandranshu suggests, would be extremely helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best I can think of is something like this:

```
    <div class="LayoutContainer">
        <div class="top"><div class="container">content</div></div>
        <div class="expand"><div class="container">content</div></div>
        <div class="top"><div class="container">content</div></div>
        <div class="top"><div class="container">content</div></div>
    </div>
```

With the CSS

```
            .top {
                float: left;
                width: 33.33%;
            }
            .expand {
                clear: both;
                width: 100%;

                position: absolute;
                top: 100px;
            }
            .top .container {
                background: #f00;
                border: 1px solid #333;
                height: 100px;
            }
            .expand .container {
                background: #0f0;
                height: 300px;
            }
            .LayoutContainer {
                position: relative;
                height: 400px;
            }
```

Though works I would not actually advice to use this. The problem here is that you would need to know the heights of the layout boxes. But if that is the case for you it would work.

Comment: Thank you! This is almost exactly what I visualized.Indeed in my case I know that the top-boxes will always have the same height. Unfortunately I am unsure about the height of the expanded box. I will see what is possible and play around with your solution a bit.

Comment: in css yet you can't make the box extend to available height as they do by default for available width, block elements. Unless you would like to use flex box model.

Comment: Just a side note, the flex box model is only IE11+ compatible, but if that not a problem for you should check out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes> for more info.

Answer (score 0):

So here is the answer, no there is not any. Why cause css isn't meant to be for that next thing you would want conditions, which is natural but again that's why we have a programming language for that.

I made a javascript.

http://jsfiddle.net/mcDrz/

```
var e=$('.extend');
$('.con').click(function(){e.html($(this).html());});
$(window).resize(setH);

function setH(){
    e.height( $(window).height()-e.offset().top );}

setH();
```